# add elements in nested list and output a list python

Tags: python

I want to add the

```
distances
[array([2.0786226e-03, 3.9023757e-03, 3.4480095e-03, 5.1999092e-04], dtype=float32), array([0.0031136 , 0.00344056, 0.00739563, 0.0311079 ],
      dtype=float32), array([1.8880665e-03, 3.0295253e-03, 4.0802956e-03, 2.6324868e-02], dtype=float32), array([0.00330418, 0.00431347, 0.00802791, 0.00426304],
      dtype=float32)]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[0.00994899872, 0.04505769, 0.0353227554, 0.0199086]
```

I tried the following but it adds all the elements and gives on scalar value

```
print(sum( sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L ))
```

Comment: What else would you expect `sum` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `L` is `distances`, you were almost there:

```
print([sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in L ])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `numpy` to do this, as

```
import numpy as np

distances = np.array([[2.0786226e-03, 3.9023757e-03, 3.4480095e-03, 5.1999092e-04],
                     [0.0031136 , 0.00344056, 0.00739563, 0.0311079 ],
                     [1.8880665e-03, 3.0295253e-03, 4.0802956e-03, 2.6324868e-02],
                     [0.00330418, 0.00431347, 0.00802791, 0.00426304]],dtype=np.float32)

print(np.sum(distances,axis=1))
```

which gives the desired output

Comment: My array has dtype=float32 which is not present in your distances array

Comment: All sub_arrays have dtype=np.float32

Comment: There also, they just doesn't stay explicity outside as yours, but you could check that out by yourself taking distances[0], that is a float32 array, as all the others.

Comment: note that you could also define each of the arrays as a 4 dimensional array with dtype=np.float32 and in the distances you could assembly them all together and do the same operation using `np,.sum`, but this of course it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Before we continue, I would like to mention you should specify that it is with numpy.

Why make a one-liner? Use a simple for loop. Take the first item in each and every list and add them up separately. To then store it, append it in a list and move on to the second item. After you find a working code, then only try shortening it. This is a good python practice.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have numpy objects inside your list you can sum these objects.

The numpy object array have the element wise implementation, so you can sum:

```
a = np.array([a1, a2, a3])
b = np.array([b1, b2, b3])
a + b
```

The result of a + b will be:

```
[a1+b1, a2+b2, a3+b3]
```

As @bruno mentioned you can use the built in method `numpy.sum` to do this automatically.